# AWS sam deploy return error invalid choice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

I'm following the instruction [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-safe-aws-lambda-deployments-with-aws-codedeploy/) to use AWS CodeDeploy to push code from GitHub to AWS.

I run into this error:

```
$ sam deploy -template-file packaged.yaml –stack-name mySafeDeployStack –capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

push                                     | register                                
deregister                               | install                                 
uninstall
```

I have previously run this command successfully:

```
$ sam package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket my-bucket --output-template-file packaged.yaml
Uploading to ...  (100.00%)
Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file packaged.yaml.
Execute the following command to deploy the packaged template
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file .../packaged.yaml --stack-name <YOUR STACK NAME>

$ sam --version
SAM CLI, version 0.6.0
```

I've tried the recommended command:

```
aws cloudformation deploy ...
```

but it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using single dashes for the flags when they require two. The `sam package` command succeeded since you used two dashes for it.

This should work:

```
sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --stack-name mySafeDeployStack --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```